# How to reuse and run same test cases in every page of application using PROTRACTOR E2E?

Tags: angular, protractor, automated-tests, angularjs-e2e

**REQUIREMENT:**

- For this example let us consider testing the look and feel of buttons through out the application based on my custom CSS styleguide
- I have written test cases to test all the states of buttons (eg. button color on hover, box shadow of buttons, css classes been used by buttons etc...)
- I want to reuse the same test cases to be used in all the pages of the application
- The application is Angular 8 and E2E is PROTRACTOR

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:**

```
// login.e2e-spec.ts

import { browser, by } from 'protractor';
import { LoginPage } from '../../pages/login.po';

describe('LOGIN page', () => {
  let page: LoginPage;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    page = new LoginPage();
    await page.navigateTo();
  });

  describe('Login form', async () => {
    it('should navigate to page containing login form', async () => {
      await expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(
        'http://localhost:4200/#/login'
      );
    });
    it('buttons suite', async () => {
      const buttons = await page.buttons.getAllButtonsByTag();
      page.buttons.testButtonsClasses(buttons);
    });
  });
});
```

```
//login.po.ts

import { Page } from '../classes/page';

export class LoginPage extends Page {
  public constructor() {
    super('login');
  }
}
```

```
//page.ts

import { browser } from 'protractor';
import { Buttons } from './buttons';
import { Url } from './url';

export class Page {
  public url: Url;
  public buttons: Buttons;

  public constructor(pageId) {
    this.url = new Url(pageId);
    this.buttons = new Buttons();
  }

  public async navigateTo(endpoint?) {
    const url = this.url['fullUrl'] + endpoint ? `/${endpoint}` : '';
    await browser.get(url);
  }
}
```

```
//buttons.ts

import { by, element } from 'protractor';
export class Buttons {
  public constructor() {}
  public getAllButtonsByTag() {
    return element.all(by.tagName('button'));
  }
  public async testButtonsClasses(buttons) {
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      const classAttribute = await buttons[i].getAttribute('class');
      expect(classAttribute).toContain('btn');
    }
  }
}
```

- In the above snaps, you can see the Logins page spec contains page specific specs.
- Im trying to use a class based structure to reuse the BUTTON's test cases.
- But this is not working as expected. The result is given below....
- The buttons cases are not runned and its always passing the parent spec.

[image: report]

- Debugged using breakpoints. Based on the screenshot the test should fail. But its still passing.

**QUESTION:**

Can someone assist in solving this issue. I'm trying to reuse the same test cases in every page.

[image]

Comment: it's better if you use the code directly, instead of images

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov Updated the question with code.

Answer (score 1):

the question is too broad. First shot in the dark would be - you need to use this

```
await buttons.get(i).getAttribute('class')
```

instead of this

```
await buttons[i].getAttribute('class')
```

---

you have a method

```
public async testButtonsClasses(buttons) {
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      const classAttribute = await buttons[i].getAttribute('class');
      expect(classAttribute).toContain('btn');
    }
  }
```

First of all use `.get(i)` instead of `[i]` and I mentioned above. Then the method is asynchronous. When something is async, it returns a promise. Any promise needs to be resolved. The best way to resolve protractor's promises is to use `await` when you call the method

```
await page.buttons.testButtonsClasses(buttons);
```

additionally, `expect` is synchronous, and doesn't need `await`. What you pass as a parameter returns a promise and DOES need `await`

```
await expect(await browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://localhost:4200/#/login');
```

Lastly, I think you're on the right track for externalizing your tests, but keep in mind it is a bad practice to put assertions in page objects. I can't name a good reason why from the top oh my head, but better to avoid it

Comment: I want to use same test cases to test buttons custom behaviour in many pages. Having said that how to reuse test cases in a functional way.

Comment: still too broad. there are many variables involved. and the result will be opinion based

Comment: wait, you are missing `await`, I'll update the answer if you paste code isntead of images

Comment: Let me try to give more detail on my problem :
- The application i'm working on is very outdated. And we are trying to migrate and optimize the styles to follow one CSS framework (Bootstrap).
- To achieve this we planned for page by page release plan.
- Also parallely when the global configuration kicks in, and when new developers start to migrate page by page, i have planned to keep E2E test cases to be runned on pages so that every HTML elements and styles follow global definitions.
- To achieve this how can i write and reuse test suite (eg for buttons ) and run in all pages? (reusable)